# If $A$ and $B$ are denumerable sets, and $C$ is a ﬁnite set, then $A \cup B \cup C$ is denumerable

Tags: elementary-set-theory, discrete-mathematics, cardinals

I have a statement here I wish to prove and I would love some help on it :)

> If $A$ and $B$ are denumerable sets, and $C$ is a ﬁnite set, then $A \cup B \cup C$ is denumerable

Here is my thoughts!

Since $A$ and $B$ are denumerable (countably infinite), then certainly we can write them as $A$ = {$a1, a2, a3...$} and we can also write $B$ as $B$ = {$b1, b2, b3...$}. My proof strategy is to prove that $A \cup B$ is denumerable and name it set $X$. Then I will proceed to demonstrate that $X \cup C$ where $C$ is finite is denumerable. Is this a valid approach?

Here I go!

The union of two denumerable sets are certainly denumerable as we can pair them off like this: {$(a1,b1), (a1,b2, (a1,b3) ... (a2,b1), (a2,b2) ....$}. We can also come up with a bijective function $f$ from $A$ to $B$ but I am not sure on how to do that! We can call the union of sets $A$ and $B$ $X$.

Anyway, so now all we have to do is prove that the $X \cup C$ is denumerable and prove that correct?

Help would be appreciated! I feel as though my professor wouldn't give me full marks as this proof is very informal unfortunately! Anything I can do?

Thanks :)

Comment: Approach is valid. You seem to confuse $A \cup B$ with the Cartesian product $A \times B$ though. Presently not very rigorous indeed, but it is important to practice proof writing early on, so that a lack of training in it won't hamper you later on. Please feel free to post your own worked out solution as an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do it all at once, but there’s nothing wrong with the idea of first proving that $X=A\cup B$ is countably infinite and then going on to prove that $X\cup C$ is as well. However, you’re off on the wrong foot in trying to prove that $X$ is countably infinite. Pairing up $A$ and $B$ isn’t going to help: what you need to do is pair up $A\cup B$ and $\Bbb Z^+$.

Writing $A=\{a_1,a_2,a_3,\dots\}=\{a_n:n\in\Bbb Z^+\}$ and $B=\{b_1,b_2,b_3,\dots\}=\{b_n:n\in\Bbb Z^+\}$ is a good start. Now let $X=A\cup B$. Informally you have $X=\{a_1,b_1,a_2,b_2,a_3,b_3\dots\}$, and it’s intuitive clear that this can be paired up with $\Bbb Z^+$:

$$\begin{array}{cc}
1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8&9&10&\dots\\
a_1&b_1&a_2&b_2&a_3&b_3&a_4&b_4&a_5&b_5&\dots
\end{array}$$

The problem is to express this clearly enough so that if someone asks what $55$ corresponds to, you can actually answer. If you examine the table above closely enough, it’s apparent that even numbers in the top line match up with $b$’s, and odd numbers with $a$’s, and a little more examination reveals the rule: $2n$ matches up with $b_n$, and $2n-1$ matches up with $a_n$. You can now express this as a bijection from $\Bbb Z^+$ to $X$:

$$f(n)=\begin{cases}
a_{\frac{n+1}2},&\text{if }n\text{ is odd}\\\\
b_{\frac{n}2},&\text{if }n\text{ is even}\;.
\end{cases}$$

> **Added:** There is just one possible problem here: if the sets $A$ and $B$ are disjoint, all is well, but this $f$ will not be a bijection if some $a_i$ is equal to some $b_k$, i.e., if $A\cap B\ne\varnothing$. To get around this, you should replace $B$ by $B\,'=B\setminus A$. If $B\,'$ is finite, let $C'=B\,'\cup C$, and use the argument below to show that $A\cup C'$ is countably infinite. And if $B\,'$ is countably infinite, use it instead of $B$ in the argument above.

Now you need to prove that $X\cup C$ is countably infinite. Since we now know that $X$ is countably infinite, there’s no need to keep the notational baggage of $a_n$’s and $b_n$’s: let $X=\{x_n:n\in\Bbb Z^+\}$ (or, more informally, $\{x_1,x_2,x_3,\dots\}$). If $C=\varnothing$, then $X\cup C=X$ is certainly countably infinite, so we can assume that $C$ is non-empty, say $C=\{c_1,\dots,c_m\}$. Now the easiest way to list $X\cup C$ systematically is $\{c_1,c_2,\dots,c_m,x_1,x_2,x_3,\dots\}$. Lay out the correspondence with $\Bbb Z^+$ as we did above:

$$\begin{array}{cc}
1&2&3&\dots&m&m+1&m+2&m+3&\dots\\
c_1&c_2&c_3&\dots&c_m&x_1&x_2&x_3&\dots
\end{array}$$

It’s not too hard not to write down a bijection $g$ from $\Bbb Z^+$ to $X\cup C$:

$$g(n)=\begin{cases}
c_n,&\text{if }1\le n\le m\\\\
x_{n-m},&\text{if }n>m\;.
\end{cases}$$

Comment: Absolutely amazing answer that cleared my doubts! If only my professors explained like you Mr.Scott! Thank you and thanks everyone for your help :)

Comment: @nicefella: You’re welcome!

Comment: The functions $f$ and $g$ are bijective if we suppose an additional assumption that the sets are disjoint.

Comment: @Sami: True; I should add a note to that effect.

Comment: @nicefella: A slight oversight in my answer was just pointed out; I’ve repaired it, and you might want to take a look.

Answer (score 2):

Suppose $X=\{x_1,x_2,\ldots\}$ is denumerable set $C=\{c_1,c_2,\ldots,c_n\}$ is finite set and without loss of generality we suppose that $X\cap C=\emptyset$ then we define the function $f:X\cup C\to\mathbb{N}$ by
$$\forall i=1,\ldots,n\quad f(c_i)=i\quad \\\mathrm{and}\\\forall i\in\mathbb{N}\quad f(x_i)=i+n$$
so it's clear that $f$ is a bijective function and then the set $X\cup C$ is denumerable.